# Не скачивается файл в Mozilla, Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Имеется rest сервис на spring, который по запросу клиента выдает файл (любой формат). Клиент (браузер) принимает файл и скачивает его. Все это отлично работает в Chrome, в Mozilla и Edge ничего не происходит.

Rest сервис:

```
byte[] data = file.getData().getData();
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFileName());
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

        try(ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
            responseOutputStream.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Клиент (angular):

```
$http({
            url: '***************',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }).success(function (data) {
            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
            saveAs(blob, fileName)
        }).error(function () {
            toastr.error('Невозможно загрузить файл', 'Ошибка');
        });
    };

    function saveAs(blob, fileName){
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var doc = document.createElement("a");
        doc.href = url;
        doc.download = fileName;
        doc.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
```

Проблема где-то на клиенте. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Я вам более того скажу, в *Safari* тоже не будет скачиваться! Как побороть пока что не знаю)

Comment: Рекомендую воспользоваться библиотекой https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/. Она прекрасно справляется с задачей сохранения `Blob`.